# why doesnt my useEffect update setUser immediately after i click button?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am currently working on building app with react native.
when i click button, why doesnt it update my user right away?

here is the code:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const getUser = async (email) => {
    try {
      console.log("get user initated, email: ", email)
      const response = await fetch(
        `http://192.168.1.128:3005/api/v1/finduser/${email}`, {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        }
      );
      console.log("response: ", response['status'])
      if (!response.ok) {
        cconsole.error(
          `This is an HTTP error: The status is ${response.status}, user not found: ${email}`
        );
      }
      let data = await response.json();
      setError(null);
      if (data) {
        console.log("type of data: ", typeof(JSON.stringify(data)))
        console.log("data: ", data[0].email)
        // setUser({ email: email })
        // console.log("user email: ", user[0].email)
        setUser(data)
        setUserFound(true);
      }
      console.log("user: ",user)
      console.log("data: ", data)
      console.log("userfound: ", userFound)
      if (!userFound) {
        navigation.navigate('Signup');
      }
    } catch(err) {
      setError(err.message);
      console.log("error message: ", err.message)
      setUser(null);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    } 
  }

  
    getUser();
  }, [user])

  const handleLogin = async () => {
    setEmailError('')
  
    if ('' === email) {
      setEmailError('Please enter your email')
    }

    try {
      await getUser(email);
    }
    catch(err) {
      setError(err.message);
    }
  }

  const handleLoginPress = () => {
    return () => {
      handleLogin(email);
    };
  };
  
  return (
    <View className={'mainContainer'} style={styles.container}>
      <View className={'titleContainer'}>
        <Text>
          Please Log In
          {"\n"}
          Connect with Google
        </Text>
      </View>
      <Text>
        {"\n"}
      </Text>
      <View className={'inputContainer'}>
        <TextInput
          value={email}
          placeholder="Enter your email here"
          onChangeText={(val) => setEmail(val)}
          className={'inputBox'}
        />
        <Text className="errorLabel">{emailError}</Text>
      </View>
      <Text>
        {"\n"}
      </Text>
      <View className={'inputContainer'}>
        <Button title={'Log in'} onPress={handleLoginPress()} />
      </View>
      <Text>{email}</Text>
    </View>
  )
};
```

i also tried separating the useEffect and getUser(),

```js
const getUser = async (email) => {
  try {
    console.log("get user initated, email: ", email);
    const response = await fetch(
      `http://192.168.1.128:3005/api/v1/finduser/${email}`,
      {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
      }
    );
    console.log("response: ", response["status"]);
    if (!response.ok) {
      cconsole.error(
        `This is an HTTP error: The status is ${response.status}, user not found: ${email}`
      );
    }
    let data = await response.json();
    setError(null);
    if (data) {
      console.log("type of data: ", typeof JSON.stringify(data));
      console.log("data: ", data[0].email);
      // setUser({ email: email })
      // console.log("user email: ", user[0].email)
      setUser(data);
      setUserFound(true);
    }
    console.log("user: ", user);
    console.log("data: ", data);
    console.log("userfound: ", userFound);
    if (!userFound) {
      navigation.navigate("Signup");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    setError(err.message);
    console.log("error message: ", err.message);
    setUser(null);
  } finally {
    setLoading(false);
  }
};

useEffect(() => {
  getUser();
}, [user]);
```

with and without user in bracket (also email). however, it does not update my user until i click it 2-3 times.

I think i tired every solutions on google, but most examples are about updating the numbers after button is clicked, but i want to update an object.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Move the `getUser` function outside of the `useEffect` hook. You should not define functions inside of it.
Then invoke `getUser` inside `useEffect` like this:

```js
await getUser();
```

Also you should await the call of `handleLogin`. Every async function should be awaited.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: i moved getUser function to outside, then when i invoke await, like below
useEffect( async () => {
    await getUser();
  }, [])
it gives me this error:
destory is not a function (it is obejct). also, not adding 'await' doesnt update user immediately

Comment: Where are you using a function called `destory`?

Comment: i'm not calling it anywhere. it now gives me useEffect must not return anything besides a function, which is used for clean-up

Comment: In your returned response (the JSON), does this word appear?

Comment: yes, it retuns 200 and console.log("data: ", data) returns data

Comment: Can you please try the following code: `useEffect(() => {
  getUser();
}, []);`

Comment: this way runs the program, but still needs to click button 2 times to set value to useState.

Answer (score 0):

you got it all wrong, **useState** will not update the value in real time world, if you try directly access it, there will be no value
you have to watch the value if change or not using **useEffect**

```
const getUser = async (email) => {
    try {
      console.log("get user initated, email: ", email)
      const response = await fetch(
        `http://192.168.1.128:3005/api/v1/finduser/${email}`, {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        }
      );
      console.log("response: ", response['status'])
      if (!response.ok) {
        cconsole.error(
          `This is an HTTP error: The status is ${response.status}, user not found: ${email}`
        );
      }
      let data = await response.json();
      setError(null);
      if (data) {
        console.log("type of data: ", typeof(JSON.stringify(data)))
        console.log("data: ", data[0].email)
        // setUser({ email: email })
        // console.log("user email: ", user[0].email)
        setUser(data)
        setUserFound(true);
      }
      console.log("user: ",user)
      console.log("data: ", data)
      console.log("userfound: ", userFound)
      if (!userFound) {
        navigation.navigate('Signup');
      }
    } catch(err) {
      setError(err.message);
      console.log("error message: ", err.message)
      setUser(null);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    } 
  }

  

  const handleLogin = async () => {
    setEmailError('')
  
    if ('' === email) {
      setEmailError('Please enter your email')
    }

    try {
      await getUser(email);
    }
    catch(err) {
      setError(err.message);
    }
  }

  const handleLoginPress = () => {
    return () => {
      handleLogin(email);
    };
  };

useEffect(() => {
// check if user is available or not
if (user) 
  // do successful login proccess
else 
 // do other unsuccessful message
  }, [user]) //watch the user value is change or not...
```